# Consulta eloquent con valores null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy creando una consulta en mediante eloquent , pero me no se como resolver el siguiente problema.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%')
                 ->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
                 ->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->paginate(50);
```

Con esta consulta puedo encontrar las coincidencias , si busco "granada" ($origen = "granada") y un registro contiene granada el la columna 'provincia' este se muestra.
El problema es si filtro por cliente ($cliente = "cualquier valor") o proveedor ($pro = "cualquier valor") y dejo en null la variable  $origen, entonces me muestra todos los registro de este cliente o proveedor salvo los que tienen valor null en la columna "provincia".

Con el código facilitado por @Manuel Robles puedo filtrar por cliente o por proveedor y me muestra todos los registros de "provincia" tengan algún valor o sean null.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%') 
->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
    ->with(['direccionescar', function($q){
        $q->whereNotNull('provincia');
    },'otrarelacion'])
    ->paginate(50);
```

La cuestión ahora es que no se como combinar ambos códigos.

Answer (score 1):

wherehas te filtrara viajes que no contengan ninguna dirección con provincia, pero si encuentra una te mostrara también las que están a null.
Mejor usa el with con una función de filtro.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%') 
    ->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
        ->with(['direccionescar', function($q){
            $q->whereNotNull('provincia');
        },'otrarelacion'])
        ->paginate(50);
```

Tambien puedes usar Scope en el modelo de Viajes por ejemplo

```
public function scopeBuscarPais($query, $paises)
    {

        if (is_null($paises)) {
            return $query;
        }

        if (is_array($paises)) {
            return $query->whereIn('id_pais', $paises);
        } else {
            return $query->where('id_pais', $paises);
        }

    }
```

y en el modelo Simplemente hacer

```
Viajes::buscarPais($request->paises)->get();
```

[DOCUMENTACIÓN SCOPE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: Con este "with" conseguimos que filtre los resultados que tienen valor null en la columna "provincia", pero como hemos de escribir la siguiente relación para que muestre solo los resultados que coincien con el valor de $origen, tal y como conseguia con la expresión ->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})

Comment: No me entero de que quieres entonces :(

Comment: He vuelta a detallar el problema de la consulta para que quede mas claro

Comment: Mírate lo de los scope que te acabo de poner

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente añadiendo unos if que comprueben si la variable a buscar es null o no he conseguido resolver el problema

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%');

 if($pro){
     $viajes = $viajes->whereHas('proveedor', function($q) use ($pro){$q->Where('name', 'like', '%'.$pro.'%');});
 }

  if($origen){
     $viajes = $viajes->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');});
 }

 $viajes = $viajes->paginate(50);
```